# Response.Redirect Not working on web application

Tags: c#, stored-procedures

Can someone help me with this? Cant fix this problem since 2 weeks. I am a beginner please help. thanks

```
public void checkSessionIfNull(string location) {
    try
    {
        if (HttpContext.Current.Session[AppUser] != null){
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect(location, false);
             HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest(); 
        }
        else{
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("../examples/login.html", false);
            HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
        }
    }catch (ThreadAbortException ex1){
        Console.WriteLine(ex1.Message.ToString());
    }catch (Exception ex) {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message.ToString());
    }
}
```

Exception:

> System.InvalidOperationException: Parameters: uEmail not found    場所
>   System.Web.Services.Protocols.ValueCollectionParameterReader.Read(NameValueCollection
>   collection)    場所
>   System.Web.Services.Protocols.UrlParameterReader.Read(HttpRequest
>   request)    場所
>   System.Web.Services.Protocols.HttpServerProtocol.ReadParameters()
>   場所
>   System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebServiceHandler.CoreProcessRequest()

C# Code

```
public string loadApplicantAccount(string uEmail, string uPword)
{
    GlobalDeclarations gd = new GlobalDeclarations();
    List<emplInfo> mylist = new List<emplInfo>();
    using (mysql.MySqlConnection connection = new mysql.MySqlConnection(connectionString()))
    {
    connection.Open();
    mysql.MySqlCommand cmd = new mysql.MySqlCommand("spLoadApplicantAcc", connection);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("uEmail", mysql.MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = uEmail;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("uPword", mysql.MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = uPword;
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.CommandTimeout = 0;

  mysql.MySqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    while (dr.Read())
    {
        mylist.Add(new emplInfo
        {
            Displayname = dr["Displayname"].ToString(),
            FullName = dr["Fullname"].ToString(),
            Access = dr["Usertype"].ToString(),
            Status = Convert.ToInt32(dr["Status"].ToString())
        });
        gd.Sessions = dr["Fullname"].ToString();
    }
    Session[gd.AppUser] = gd.Sessions;
    dr.Close();
    connection.Close();
    gd.checkSessionIfNull("../examples/appHunt_IndexPage.html");
}
    JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    string jsn = jss.Serialize(mylist);
    return jsn;
}
```

Stored Procedure:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `spLoadApplicantAcc`(IN `uEmail` VARCHAR(50), IN `uPword` VARCHAR(50))
BEGIN
    SELECT *
        FROM appuser
        where (appuser.Email = uEmail or appuser.Username = uEmail)
         and (appuser.Email != '' or appuser.Username != '' or appuser.Email != null or appuser.Username != null)
         and appuser.Password = uPword;
END
```

Comment: Are you getting any exceptions? What headers does the client receive? Is this ASP.NET? ASP.NET Core?

Comment: @John Yes Sir. I have an exception received. `System.InvalidOperationException: パラメーター: uEmail が見つかりません。
   場所 System.Web.Services.Protocols.ValueCollectionParameterReader.Read(NameValueCollection collection)
   場所 System.Web.Services.Protocols.UrlParameterReader.Read(HttpRequest request)
   場所 System.Web.Services.Protocols.HttpServerProtocol.ReadParameters()
   場所 System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebServiceHandler.CoreProcessRequest()`

Comment: @John Sir. I posted the code regarding the exception thrown sir.

Comment: A quick google translate of the error message: "Parameters: uEmail not found. place"

Comment: @bradbury9 But Sir, As you can see the `uEmail` is existing on that code.

Comment: Well, does it exist as an input paramter in your `spLoadApplicantAcc` stored procedure?

Comment: @bradbury9 Yes sir, Actually, all of the parameter name from ajax to stored procedure and c# is the same

Comment: Looks like database related: Edit your question and a) Add the mysql tag. b) Add the stored procedure declaration. Despite the wrong namespace, the database code looks fine,

Comment: @Karan I added the symbol @ and then this is the exception thrown now `{"Message":"認証に失敗しました。","StackTrace":null,"ExceptionType":"System.InvalidOperationException"}{"d":"[{\"Displayname\":\"Drake Alexis\",\"FullName\":\"Alexis Abulencia Villar\",\"Status\":0,\"Access\":\"Applicant\"}]"}`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196796/discussion-between-bradbury9-and-alex-abulencia).

Answer (score 2):

The error message

> Parameters: uEmail not found

Is because in your stored procedure you are missing the parameter delimiter and it cannot differentiate between a column name named "uEmail" and your parameter names. You can check the mySql documentation [Working with Parameters](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-tutorials-parameters.html)

Edit: Changed the NULL and string empty checks to make it work, it was a second problem you had with the SQL

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `spLoadApplicantAcc`(IN `uEmail` VARCHAR(50), IN `uPword` VARCHAR(50))
BEGIN
        SELECT *
        FROM appuser
        where 
        (
            ifnull(app.Email, '') = @uEmail or ifnull(app.Username, '') = @uEmail
        )
        and appuser.Password = @uPword;
END
```

Comment: Hi Sir, is this applicable in wamp server?

Comment: There is a problem after I add the `@` on the parameters inside the stored procedure, it cant get the equal value entered by the user sir.

Comment: Looks like you got confused with the null checks, check my edit for a simplified version of your logic calling [ifnull(expression, alt_value) function](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_ifnull.asp)

Comment: Hi Sir. After I test the edited stored procedure. Still does not work. The same exception returned.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have 2 dots at the start of the relative url `("../examples/login.html")`. If your relative url starts with `"/"` it will be relative to the root.

If you change the name of parameters in the stored procedure, you also need to add parameters with these names in your C# code.

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@uEmail", uEmail);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@uPword", uPword);
```

Comment: Because, every file of js, c#, and webservice, and also the HTML files are different sir

Comment: Ok, have you tested to use an absolute url in Response.Redirect?

Comment: different folder sir

Comment: Yes Sir. Actually, If i remove the code `Response.Redirect` it works fine. but then if I add that. the exception exist. didnt know how to fix this

Comment: Ok, test with Response.Redirect("/", false);

Comment: Sir? still the same